# Black text appears grey in Android View

Tags: android, colors, textview, viewflipper

I'm using a ViewFlipper to alternate some different RelativeLayouts.  My layout is very simple.

```
<RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/display_info_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/information"
                    android:color="@color/black" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
The color named "black" is defined in my resources as "#000000".  The text elements appear the correct black color in other layouts, but in this one it appears a dull grey.

Other Layout
[image: Other layout with normal black text]

This Layout
[image: This layout with grey text]

**THE QUESTIONS:**

1. What could be causing this?
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [android:textColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3atextColor) I don't think android:color exists as an attribute

So:

```
                 <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/information"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  You are correct.  I'm not sure why the Eclipse editor didn't flag it or throw a warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

`ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), color)` fixed the issue for me